# PHP - Janela MODAL

Tags: php, select, bootstrap-3, input, modal

Já tentei alguns scripts mas sem sucesso, peço perdão se tem em algum fórum já, porém procurei a respeito de modal e nada supriu minha necessidade, lá vai:

Tenho um modal dentro do button Cliente, que ao clicar carrega uma tabela com dados vindos do banco de dados, queria saber qual script utilizar para fazer essa tabela receber clique e adicionar o que foi selecionado dentro do input

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Modal do Vitão</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .modal .modal-dialog { width: 60%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>                    
                <div class="container">
                <h2>Modal</h2>

                <div class="modal fade" id="Modal" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <table class="table">
                            <?php
                              include ("conn.php");

                                    echo "<table border = 1>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>Código</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Nome Fantasia</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Cliente</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Código Interno</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Endereço</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";

                                $result = "SELECT codigo, nome_fantasia, cliente, codigo_interno, nome_logr from cadcli";
                                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                                    $codigo = $row['codigo'];
                                    $nome_fantasia =  $row['nome_fantasia'];
                                    $cliente= $row['cliente'];
                                    $codigo_interno = $row['codigo_interno'];
                                    $nome_logr = $row['nome_logr'];

                                    echo"</tr>";
                                    echo "<td>$codigo</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$nome_fantasia</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$cliente</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$codigo_interno</td>";
                                    echo "<td>$nome_logr</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">Cliente >></button><br/>
                <input type="text" name="cliente">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro: Você está printando opções fora de um select.

Básicamente, só precisa incluir um evento ao select dentro da modal, ao mudar o valor do select trigera o fechamento da modal e o preenchimento do input com o valor selecionado:

Mesmo código seu mas fazendo o que você quer, veja no final o disparador jQuery, e os classnames adicionados ao input e ao select :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .modal .modal-dialog { width: 50%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Modal</h2>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Unidade</button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control unidade-input" name="unidade">
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <label class="modal-title">Unidade</label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <select class='select-input'>
                        <?php
                          include ("conn.php");
                          $result = "SELECT * FROM cadunid ORDER BY descricao";
                          $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $result);
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
                          echo '<option value="'.$row['codigo'].'">'.$row['descricao'].'</option>';
                          }

                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
<script>
    $(document).on('change', '.select-input', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.close').trigger('click');
        $('.unidade-input').val(value);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, ajudou bastante. Mas e com uma table dentro de um modal ?
Tentei trocar o comando SELECT por TABLE e fechar a TABLE mas não funcionou

Comment: Se quiser usar TABLE, precisa colocar os valores em TRs e TDs, e mudar o evento 'change' para 'click' e apontador para um classname em comum entre as unidades

Comment: É outro caso, o da unidade você resolveu perfeitamente como queria cara, porém esse caso é uma tabela que abre dentro do modal com dados dos clientes usuários do sistema com os campos NOME, CODIGO, NOME FANTASIA, ENDEREÇO, e ai seleciono o desejado.

Comment: é Basicamente a mesma coisa que você fez ali em cima, só que   estrurua de tabela é diferente de select, seria '<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>' TR são as linhas, e TD são as colunas, vc ta usando o bootstrap 3 ? da uma olhada no fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/AnthraxisBR/am9zpa9s/

Comment: dei uma olhada lá,, porém a modal não é selecionável como o select, é que eu comecei a programar faz uns meses em php e nunca mexi com js e php to meio perdido cara... Eu colei o código no lugar da minha antiga dúvida sem o script